# Start, stop, restart Glassfish Server from java desktop application

Tags: java, glassfish

I am developing a project that needs booth a web and desktop application. The web app receives the tasks from my clients and stores them (in database). The desktop application gets the tasks (from database) and execute them one by one. In my web application i am using java servlets, web services ...

Sometimes my glassfish server (v 3.1.2) freezes or he becomes blocked and needs to be restarted so he can continue work properly. I can detect this kind of error by monitoring him and find out when he freezes (by calling simple web service method that throws exception, simple http request that also throws exception etc).

I want my desktop application get the Glassfish server status and if

1. "Everything is ok" then "Do nothing"
2. "Server is down" then "Start Glassfish Server"
3. "I detect an error" then "Restart Glassfish Server"
4. "Application quit" then "Shutdown Glassfish Server"

Does anyone had this problem and has any solution. I am tired of manually restarting the glassfish server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own solution that i want to share.

When i detect that something is wrong with my Glassfish server, i restart it. This solutions only works on Linux (i will edit this answer if i find simular for windows users). Also u might have to add this line for your user in "/etc/sudoers" under root user, adrian is my username.

```
adrian  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

GlassFish Class: (U will need to change glassfishPath and domainName with yours)

```
    package es.web.glassfish;

    import es.os.linux.Konsole;
    import java.io.IOException;

    /**
     *
     * @author adrian
     */
    public class Glassfish {

    private final static String glassfishPath = "/home/adrian/glassfish-4.0/";
    private final static String domainName = "domain1";

    public static String startGlassfishServer() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String command = glassfishPath + "bin/asadmin start-domain "+domainName;
        return Konsole.executeCommand(command);
    }

    public static String stopGlassfishServer() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String command = glassfishPath + "bin/asadmin stop-domain "+domainName;
        return Konsole.executeCommand(command);
    }

    public static String restrartGlassfishServer() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String command = glassfishPath + "bin/asadmin restart-domain "+domainName;
        return Konsole.executeCommand(command);
    }

}
```

Konsole Class:

```
package es.os.linux;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

/**
 *
 * @author adrian
 */
public class Konsole {

    static Process process;
    static BufferedReader reader;

    public static String executeCommand(String command) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String rez = "";
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        process.waitFor();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            rez += line + "#";
        }
        return rez;
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
public class test {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            System.out.println("START");
            System.out.println(Glassfish.startGlassfishServer());
            System.out.println("RESTART");
            System.out.println(Glassfish.restrartGlassfishServer());
            System.out.println("STOP");
            System.out.println(Glassfish.stopGlassfishServer());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Test class output:

```
START
Waiting for domain1 to start ............#Successfully started the domain : domain1#domain  Location: /home/adrian/glassfish-4.0/glassfish/domains/domain1#Log File: /home/adrian/glassfish-4.0/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log#Admin Port: 4848#Command start-domain executed successfully.#
RESTART
Successfully restarted the domain#Command restart-domain executed successfully.#
STOP
Waiting for the domain to stop #Command stop-domain executed successfully.#
```

Comment: Again see my comment above. Additionally you are not properly using the Process/Runtime exec APIs. You are reading the input stream in the same thread that you are executing the Process. That's a great way to have a thread deadlock occur at seeming random executions.

Comment: I know that your answer was useful, but did not solve my problem. This solution can also starts the glassfish server from desktop application when it is stoped. Restart command starts the server when it is down, and restarts the server when is started.

Answer (score 3):

I run Glassfish 3.1.2 in production for months at a time without issue. I would suspect the freezing your are seeing is a problem with the application you have deployed to it.

I think you would be best served spending time investigating and remediating your hanging issue. Have you tried taking a thread dump of the Glassfish java process when this happens?

Comment: The problem is either i cannot call webservice method or the http client doesn't receive any data. Tried many things, only restart works.

Comment: That suggests that your application is starving the HTTP thread pool. Again, you should take a thread dump when you encounter this so you can see what's going on.

Comment: I increased the http thread pool and since then i have no problems, but if sometimes occur, i would like to restart the server i find out after what was the problem.